# How to bundle a Node TS/JS library with Webpack?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I have a Node project:

- Codebase in Typescript
- Bundled via Webpack and `ts-loader`
- Target platform: Node.js

```
+-proj/
  +-src/
    |-file1.ts
    |-file2.ts
    |-file3.ts
    |-...
  |-package.json
  |-webpack.config.json
  |-tsconfig.json
```

This project is supposed to be a library. I need to build a bundle that in the end can be consumed by other Typescript projects targeting Node.

### The problem

Any code consuming that final bundle will need to access only some classes I defined inside `file1.ts` and `file2.ts`. All other source files export stuff, but those are eventually referenced by those two files and I want the final library to expose only the components defined inside these two files.

```
// file1.ts

export class MyComponent1 {...}
export function myFunc() {...}
```

```
// file2.ts

import { MyComponent3 } from "./file3"

export class MyComponent2 {...}
export function myOtherFunc() {...}
```

```
// file3.ts

export class MyComponent3 {...}
```

Given the files above, the final bundle should expose `MyComponent2`, `MyComponent2`, `myFunc` and `myOtherFunc`.

### Question

My problem is that I do not how to configure Webpack. It needs an entry point, but I need to expose many different things under `src`, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a single file that would serve as the entry point. For example, it can be named **main.ts** or **index.ts** or anything you prefer.

The contents of the file would just re-exporting the contents of the files you want to be public:

```typescript
export * from "./file1";
export * from "./file2";
```

If you want to export only some thing and not all from each file. Assuming **file1** exports `a`, `b`, and `c` while **file2** exports `d`, `e`, and `f` you can specify a subset like this:

```typescript
export { a, b } from "./file1";
export { e, f } from "./file2";
```

Then you can configure Webpack to use your file in webpack.conf.js:

```javascript
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/main.ts", //or your choice of name
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Ah I re-export... makes sense. I was trying this technique but I was using `import` instead to reference all the files I wanted but it did not work. Lemme try this.